# Foreign key references invalid table

Tags: sql

I have the following code:

```
create table test.dbo.Users
(
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Name varchar(36) not null
)

create table test.dbo.Number
(
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Number varchar(10) not null,
    Name varchar(36) not null foreign key references Users.Name
)
```

The foreign key throws an error saying `Foreign key 'FK__Number__Name__1CF15040' references invalid table 'Users.Name'.`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't think it is USERS.NAME, it should be USERS(NAME). check the extact syntax

Comment: @Santhosh: That solves the problem with reference. Thanks! Although, now I got an error saying that there are no matching candidates for this foreign key in `Users` table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see in this SQLfiddle link, [Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a105/2)

```
CREATE TABLE NUMBER(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    NUMBER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL REFERENCES USERS(NAME)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Foreign key must reference a primary key in another table

I would use the following code

I hope it is useful

```
use test
create table test.dbo.Users
(
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Name varchar(36) not null
)

create table test.dbo.Number
(
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Number varchar(10) not null,
    Users_Id int not null

    constraint fk_Number_Users foreign key (Users_Id) 
               references Users(Id)
               on update no action
               on delete no action
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should reference the Primary Key of test.dbo.users.

In SQL Server you could do this:

```
create table Number
(
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Number varchar(10) not null,
    Name varchar(36) not null ,
    Id_FK int not null foreign key references Users(id)
)
```

In the above, you have a mandatory association between the 2 tables. If you want to have optional relationship, remove the 'not null' from Id_Fk....

Note: I don't know what is the Name column for.

Comment: Yeah, probably shouldn't reference `Name`. But what If I needed that? How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

For people who were 100% positive that Table does exist, like I was, please be sure to check web.config. I had a typo in there and it was giving this error, which is counter-intuitive if you ask me, but that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a bunch of scripts to create tables, It might worth to make sure the referenced table script is running before the consumer table.

Answer (score 0):

```
use [database];
```

and then create table. 
Works for me.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Really what needs to be explained? If before create table wasn't "use database" occurs exact error as in question. Thats all was perfectly described in this 2 lines.